# Client-side JS autocomplete not working with VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When I attempt to write plain client-side JS, I do not get any suggestions or autocomplete at all. Even for something as simple as `console.log()`, the editor does not provide any method suggestions.

However, when I use a JS runtime such as Deno, this is not the case.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. also include what language mode you see in the language mode indicator in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the `settings` in **VS Code**, search for `suggestion` and go to the screen (shown in the image).

If you notice the first item `other` has the value `off` under `Quick Suggestions`, then update it to `on`. You should start seeing the intellisense then.

[image]

[image]